# ASP.NET Web API Key Authentication| Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-api-management, api-key, asp.net-apicontroller

I've almost finished my `web API project` using `ASP.NET` and I'd like to publish this API on `Azure`. What is the best way to use `API key authentication` for the endpoints for the users?

For example: `https://api.test.org/data&key=**{API key}**`

At this moment I've my own API key in `appsettings.json` and I compare the given key from the header, with this key, but I don't know if this is correct. Is it for example possible to connect my ASP.NET API project with Azure API Management and use a Azure key?

Comment: who or what are you trying to authorize?  (for instance an application could be authorized, or a group of users, or a particular server...)

Comment: The application

Comment: You'll probably want to use a cert... maybe check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app

Answer (score 0):

> Is it for example possible to connect my ASP.NET API project with Azure API Management and use a Azure key?

If you want to host it within the APIM, you can use this as a Backend Service.

You can also use the `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` Header or query parameter for getting the APIKey Authentication when you published this API inside the Azure API Management - Product Service.